# Efron-Stein Inequality proof clarification.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am currently going through the proof of the Efron-Stein inequality in this set of notes ([http://www.econ.upf.edu/~lugosi/mlss_conc.pdf](http://www.econ.upf.edu/%7Elugosi/mlss_conc.pdf))(P.g. 219-220). However, I have an issue with the final part of the proof where they use the following fact:$$\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\frac{1}{2}E[(Y-Y')^2] \text{, where Y' is an independent copy of Y}$$ to prove that $$E_i[(Z-E_i[Z])^2]=\frac{1}{2}E_i[(Z-Z_i')^2].$$ Can anyone show me how the fact is used in proving the above statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\operatorname{Var}_i(Z) =\frac{1}{2} E_i[(Z-E_i[Z])^2] $. Now $E_i$ is the conditional  expectation where all the random variables are given except the $i$-th. Finally note that conditional on $(X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\ldots,X_n)$, $Z$ and $Z_i'$ are independent. Thus the result follows.

Comment: Thanks.But why are they independent conditional on $(X_1,..,X_{i-1},X_{i+1}..,X_n)$

Comment: The short answer is "by defition of conditional expectation". Long answer: in the quantity  $E_i(Z) = E(g(X_1,\ldots,X_n)|X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\ldots,X_n)$, $X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\ldots,X_n$ are given, and therefore you can treat them as constants. The only source of randomness in the expectation comes from $X_i$.

Comment: By the way is $E_i[Z^2]=E_i[Z_i'^2]$? If so why? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. In fact, much more is true. conditional on $(X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\ldots,X_n)$, $Z = g(X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1},X_i, X_{i+1},\ldots,X_n)$ and $Z_i' = g(X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1},X_i', X_{i+1},\ldots,X_n)$ are independent and identically distributed. Again to see this consider $(X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\ldots,X_n)$ to be known (as they are given). The only source of randomness comes from $X_i$ and $X_i'$, and they are independent copy of the same random variable.

Comment: Im sorry but is it possible for you to show their independence using the sigma algebra notation instead.

Comment: and their identical distribution. Thanks

Comment: That is a completely different question regarding conditional expectation. You can make another post perhaps?

Comment: I did thanks. Btw could you look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036661/if-x-n-n-in-mathbbn-is-a-martingale-s-t-sup-n-ex-n-leq-m-inft if you dont mind. Maybe you might know how to solve it. I have been stuck for some time now.