# Independence of functions of independent random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

Suppose $X_1,..,X_n$ are independent random variables and $X_i'$ is an independent copy of $X_i$, then how does one show that $$E[f(X_1,..,X_n)|X_1,..,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},..,X_n]$$ and  $$E[f(X_1,..,X_i',..,X_n)|X_1,..,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},..,X_n]$$ are equal almost everywhere and why is $f(X_1,..,X_n)$ and $f(X_1,..,X_i',..,X_n)$ conditionally independent over $G:=\sigma(X_1,..,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},..,X_n)$?

I am trying to argue using measure theoretic arguments but I can't seem to be able to show this. I am stuck trying to understand the $\sigma$-algebras generated by both functions which are measurable on $\sigma(X_1,..,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},..,X_n)$. Any ideas?

i.e. Possible proof of conditional independence:

Note: $\sigma(f(X_1,..,X_n))\subset \sigma(X_1,..,X_n)$ and $\sigma(f(X_1,..,X_i',..,X_n))\subset \sigma(X_1,..,X_i',..,X_n)$. Let $A\in  \sigma(X_1)\cup...\cup\sigma(X_n) $ and $B\in \sigma(X_1)\cup..\cup\sigma(X_i')..\cup\sigma(X_n)$ then $$E[1_A1_B|G]=E[1_A|G]E[1_B|G]$$
This implies that it holds for all $A\in \sigma(X_1,..,X_n)$ and $B\in \sigma(X_1,..,X_i',..,X_n)$.

Comment: I applaud you exploring this question from the fundamental level. Intuitive yes, yet dig in and demonstrate.

Comment: Uh, why are these independent? Did you mean to write X_i and X'_i in conditioning? (Otherwise take f(x_1, ..., x_n) = x_1 and i=2). (I guess conversely, you might have meant that these are equal almost surely which should be true)

Comment: Yes you are right. $f(X_1,..,X_n)$ and $f(X_1,..,X_i',..X_n)$ are conditional independent on  $(X_1,..,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},..,X_n)$

Comment: @E-A Do you know why they might be equal a.e.

Comment: When you say "copy", I assume you mean a second drawing ?

Comment: A variable that is independent from Y and has the same distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y=[X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]$. Then
$$
\mathsf{E}[f(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1},X_n)\mid Y]=\varphi(Y) \quad\text{a.s.}
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{E}[f(X_1,\ldots, X_{n-1},X_n')\mid Y]=\varphi'(Y) \quad\text{a.s.},
$$
where $\varphi(y)=\mathsf{E}f(y_1,\ldots, y_{n-1}, X_n)$ and $\varphi'(y)=\mathsf{E}f(y_1,\ldots, y_{n-1}, X_n')$. (See, e.g., Lemma 6.2.1 on page 236 [here](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Emanuelg/arquivos/Probability:%20Theory%20and%20Examples%20-%20Durrett.pdf).) But $\varphi(y)=\varphi'(y)$ because $X_n\overset{d}{=}X_n'$.

Comment: Thanks. but where is y from? Is $y\in Y$ and $y_i\in X_i$

Comment: $y$ is a vector of numbers, where each $y_i$ represents a realization of $X_i$, $1\le i\le n-1$.

Comment: Thank you btw is the proof for conditional independence correct? Also do you have any ideas for the following problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036661/if-x-n-n-in-mathbbn-is-a-martingale-s-t-sup-n-ex-n-leq-m-inft

Comment: @JhonDoe It is not clear how you choose the sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Oh for instance A is in the generating set of $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$ i.e. $A=X_i^{-1}(B)$ for some Borel set. Similarly for B.

Comment: So, $A$ is of the form $A_1\cap A_2\cap\ldots \cap A_n$...

Comment: $\sigma(X_1,..,X_n)=\sigma(X_i^{-1}(B)|i\in\{1,..,n\}, \text{ B is a Borel set })$ so $A=X_i^{-1}(B)$ for some $i$ which is I guess what you wrote with $A_i=X_i^{-1}(B)$ and $A_j=X_j^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: So how do you show the result for any set in $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$?

Comment: I define $\sum=\{L\in \sigma(X_1,..,X_n)|E[1_L1_B|G]=E[1_L|G]E[1_B|G] \text{ for all generating sets B of $\sigma(X_1,..,X_i',..,X_n)$} \}$. I show that this is a sigma algebra that contains $\sigma(X_1,..,X_n)$.

Comment: Once i have shown that for $\sum$, I define $\sum_2:=\{L\in\sigma(X_1,..,X_i',..,X_n)|E[1_A1_L|G]=E[1_A|G]E[1_L|G] \text{for all A in $\sigma(X_1,..,X_n)$ }\}$. This also a sigma algebra that contains \sigma(X_1,..,X_i',..,X_n).

Comment: I meant that you probably need to invoke  the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem as shown in Proposition 14 [here](https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~vidmarm/Dynkin_and_pi_systems.pdf).

Comment: I think in this situation you dont need to as the way $\sum$ and $\sum_2$ were defined suffices.

Comment: Btw the proof of the theorem you are using in your ans makes use of monotone class theorem which holds only for bounded measurable functions but we can extend the result to integrable functions through MCT right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.