# Control the sum of the square of martingale increments

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales

- Question:

Let $X_n$ is a martingale, which is $L^1$ bounded： $\sup_{n}E[|X_n|]=K<\infty$. Prove
$$
\sum_{i=2}^\infty (X_i-X_{i-1})^2<\infty,\ a.s.
$$

- Other information:

Our prof gives a hint. He let us consider a truncation. Introduce a stopping time $\tau_L:=\inf\{n:|X_n|\ge L\}$, to show
$$
E[\sum_{i=2}^n (X_i-X_{i-1})^2 1_{\{\tau_L> n\}}]
$$
is uniformly bounded in $n$.

- My confusion:

I do not know how to deal with the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X_{i-1})^2 1_{\{\tau_L> n\}}$. Do we have $
E[\sum_{i=2}^n (X_i-X_{i-1})^2 1_{\{\tau_L> n\}}]= E[(X_n-X_1)^2 1_{\{\tau_L> n\}}]\le 4L^2$?
I want to show
$$
E[\sum_{i=2}^\infty (X_i-X_{i-1})^2]<\infty
$$

Comment: Pls refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4039126

Comment: Thank you. I find the answer now. We can also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036661/if-x-n-n-in-mathbbn-is-a-martingale-s-t-sup-n-ex-n-leq-m-inft/4043115#4043115

Comment: I have doubts about the validity of the claim made in the hint you were provided.  Have you succeeded in confirming it?

Comment: Yes, that is right. When proving it, you should replace ${\tau_L>n}$ by ${\tau_L>i-1}$, then you can use martingale property to control it. You can consider $E[(X_i-X_{i-1})^21_{\tau_L>\{i-1\}}]$ and you will find some items can be cancelled. It is not very easy.

Comment: Using the fact that $X$ stopped at $\tau_L$ is a martingale, so has orthogonal increments, it's standard that 
$$
E[(X_{n\wedge\tau_L}-X_0)^2]=E\left[\sum_{i=2}^n(X_i-X_{i-1})^21_{\{\tau_L>i-1\}}\right],
$$
But the expectation on the left can be large if $X_{\tau_L}$ is large on $\{n=\tau_L\}$.
Austin's argument (in the paper referred by JGWang) is more subtle.